# jquery dialog - multiple dialogs on page, only open one at a time

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog

I have 12 dialogs on one page. I only want them to open if neither of the other 12 dialogs are open. I don't want it to close the existing and open a new one, I simply want it to only open one dialog at a time, and stop the user from being able to open two at a time.

Sample HTML:

```
               <div id="thumb2" class="suiting-thumb">
                    <img src="img/gallery/suit1-thumb.jpg" alt="" title="" />
                </div>
                <div id="galleryDialog2" class="galleryDialog">
                    <a id="prev-arrow" href="#"></a> 
                    <a id="next-arrow" href="#"></a>
                    <div class="text">
                        text and link
                    </div>
                    <div class="dialog-slider">
                       <img src="img/suiting-details/custom-suiting-vent-styles.jpg" alt="" title="" />                       
                       <img src="img/suiting-details/custom-suit-coat-lining.jpg" alt="" title="" />
                   </div>
               </div>
```

JS:

```
        /* Gallery Dialog Settings */
        $('[id^=galleryDialog]').dialog({ 
                width: 480,
                height:479, /* 479 seems to be the magic number to get the box to fit vertically on the slider */
                show: 'fade',
                hide: 'fade',
                autoOpen: false,
                draggable: false,
                open: function() {
                    $('#four').stop().fadeTo("fast", 0.3);
                    $('.suiting-thumb').stop().fadeTo("fast", 1.0);
                    $("a#prev").attr("id","prev-false");
                    $("a#next").attr("id", "next-false");
                    $('.suiting-thumb').attr('class', 'suiting-thumb-false');
                },
                close: function() {
                    $('#four').stop().fadeTo("normal", 1);
                    $("a#prev-false").attr("id","prev");
                    $("a#next-false").attr("id", "next");
                    $('.suiting-thumb-false').attr('class', 'suiting-thumb');
                }
        });

        $('.suiting-thumb').click(function() {
            //strip off prefix of thumb id to get number for dialog
            var thumbBtnIdPrefix = 'thumb';
            var thumbBtnNum = $(this).attr('id').substring((thumbBtnIdPrefix.length));
            if(!$('.galleryDialog').dialog("isOpen")) {
                $('#galleryDialog' + thumbBtnNum).dialog('open').dialog('widget').position({ 
                    at: 'center center', 
                    of: $('#slider'),
                    offset: "75 0"
                });
            }
        });
```

I'm trying to use an if statemenet that checka to see if ".galleryDialog", a class applied to all dialog divs, is not open. If not open, then open the clicked dialog. This works properly whenever you open "galleryDialog1", but when I close the first and open a different one, you can then open as many as you'd like, all at once.

Any help would be amazing. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could just set a global boolean value then check that value before opening a new dialog?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why don't you add `modal: true` to the dialog calls, that way you can only view one at a time.

Comment: @nickff, remember to select an `accepted answer` when you can